# Webpack follow import path to avoid the need of tree shaking

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, tree-shaking, webpack-loader

I have some issues with tree shaking in my webpack 3 configuration (maybe) because I use a lot of re-exports.
I'd like to keep the reexports but avoid the unnecessary increase in my bundle size. (Plus I'd also like to avoid unnecessary code in my dev build)
So I was wondering if there is a way to like "follow" the imports through the files and replace them with a direct path to the module.

#### Code 1:

index.js:

```
import {x} from './Folder1';
```

Folder1/index.js:

```
export {x} from './Folder2';
export {y} from './SomeOtherFolder';
```

Folder1/Folder2/index.js:

```
export {x} from './x.js';
```

So (without tree shaking and sometimes with webpack's somehow broken tree shaking) `x` **and** `y` would be included in my bundle, which wouldn't happen if I had the following import statement:

#### Code 2

index.js:

```
import {x} from './Folder1/Folder2/x.js';
```

Well... is it possible to get from Code 1 to Code 2 during the build process with webpack (or any other tool)?